# Why unit test getting failed in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito

I'm working on spring boot project. All things work perfectly but while unit testing `saveBooking()` method of controller then unit testing become failure. In Failure Trace I get `java.lang.AssertionError: Response content expected:<Saved> but was:<SAVED>`. This code worke perfectly in my postman but failure in unit testing.

Here down is my code:

*Model*

```
public class Booking {
    private String bookingId;
    private String passangerName;
    private String flightName;
    private String source;
    private String destination;
    
    // constructor, getter and setter
}
```

*Controller*

```
@RestController
public class BookingController {

    @Autowired
    private BookingService bookingService;

    @PostMapping("/booking")
    public String saveBooking(@RequestBody Booking booking) {
        boolean saved = bookingService.saveBooking(booking);
        return "SAVED";

    }
}
```

*TestController*

```
@WebMvcTest(controllers = BookingController.class)
public class BookingControllerTest {

    @MockBean
    private BookingService bookingService;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    
    @Test
    public void testSaveBooking() throws Exception
    {
        Mockito.when(bookingService.saveBooking(any())).thenReturn(true);
        String bookingDetails = "{\r\n"
                + "    \"bookingId\": \"AA0456\",\r\n"
                + "    \"passangerName\": \"Michael\",\r\n"
                + "    \"flightName\": \"Air American\",\r\n"
                + "    \"source\": \"California\",\r\n"
                + "    \"destination\": \"Dubai\"\r\n"
                + "}";
        RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/booking").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(bookingDetails);
        mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder).andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk()).andExpect(content().string("Saved"));
    }

}
```

Comment: Because your test expects something different than the result.

Comment: returning SAVED and expecting it to be Saved is failing the test

Comment: @DaveNewton Much thanks for help my problem is solved

Answer (score 2):

SAVED != Saved

```
 return "SAVED";
```

but expect

```
andExpect(content().string("Saved"));
```

Solution 1:
Try to use an enum so you can't misspell it

Solution 2:

check the string with .toLowerCase() when you check, so the case doesn't matter.

Solution 3:

Use

```
return "SAVED";
```

and

```
andExpect(content().string("SAVED"));
```

so the strings match.